# Select a new number from array every second randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        b = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.id = "canvas"
        
        canvas.width = 900;
        canvas.height = 600;
        
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        
        
        
        var posX =  430;
        posY = 300;
        
        var myArray = [-3.5,0,3.5];
        
        var dX = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
        var dY = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
      
       
        
        setInterval(function (){
                b.fillStyle = "steelblue";
                b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                posX += dX;
                posY += dY;
            
                if (posX > 875){
                    dX = 0;
                    posX = 875;
                }
                if (posX < 5){
                    dx = 0;
                    posX = 5;
                }
                if (posY > 575){
                        dY = 0;
                        posY = 575;
                }
                if (posY < 5){
                        dY = 0;
                        posY = 5;
                }
        
        b.fillStyle = "snow";
        b.fillRect(posX, posY, 20, 20);
        }, 20)
```

This is all my Code. I want to move the cube on the background randomly. Right now it moves in just one random direction. but I want it to change this direction every second. for that dX and dY have to change every each second.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: use setInterval

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:
If you have any questions about the code. Feel free to write a comment.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = 100
canvas.height = 100
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'steelblue'
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const RADIUS = 5
const SPEED = 0.6
let pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2]
let direction = [0, 0]

setInterval(function() {
    pos[0] += direction[0] * SPEED
    pos[1] += direction[1] * SPEED

    if(pos[0] <= RADIUS || pos[0] >= canvas.width - RADIUS ||
    pos[1] <= RADIUS || pos[1] >= canvas.height - RADIUS) {
        pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2] 
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "snow"
    ctx.fillRect(pos[0] - RADIUS, pos[1] - RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS)
}, 20)

setInterval(function() {
    const randomAngle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI
    direction = [Math.cos(randomAngle), Math.sin(randomAngle)]
}, 1000)
```

Comment: one question: now the little square jumps to the center when it touches the walls. why is that?

Comment: So in the if check ```if(pos[0] <= RADIUS || pos[0] >= canvas.width - RADIUS ||
    pos[1] <= RADIUS || pos[1] >= canvas.height - RADIUS)```
I check if the box its out of bounce. And if so teleport to the middle
with ```pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2] ```

Comment: thanks. Lets say I want to give the little square some more properties like disappearing after some time and cloning after some time. I can't find where in the code is the exact point when you defined the square as a variable. is there any way that I give it an ID so I can call functions on it?(like cloning and disapperaring

Comment: sorry I'm a complete beginner trying to learn to code:/

Comment: Maybe I can use something like this:  var ctx_1 = ctx.cloneNode(true);   ?

Comment: Or lets just say I don't want to clone the box but just have two of them at the same time

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval()` https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

```js
var myArray = [-3.5,0,3.5];
var dX, dY

setInterval(() => {
  dX = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  dY = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I tried that too. But my plane just vanishes and doesn't give me any error message.

Comment: Oh, you want to make a game so it would be great to close that question and open a new CLEAN question in which you describe what you want to do and what your problem is.

Comment: in that case you need to add 

var dX = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
var dY = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
       
inside the setInterval you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally opt to use `Array.prototype` to add a method which will get a random element of the array, and then use `setInterval` to update the values evey second:

```js
Array.prototype.getRandom = function() {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
  return this[index];
}

var myArray = [-3.5,0,3.5];
var dX, dY;

function updateDerivatives() {
  dX = myArray.getRandom(),
  dY = myArray.getRandom();
  console.log("Updated values:", { dX, dY });
}

setInterval(updateDerivatives, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [-3.5,0,3.5];

var dX;
var dY;

setInterval(() => { // you could also use setInterval(function(){...},...)
    dX = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
    dY = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
}, 1000) // 1000 milliseconds
```

Comment: I tried. But now the plane has vanished. But I do not get any error message